# How to use multiple values of property key from property file in java

Tags: java

In config.properties file, there will be users key will multiple users as property values. There may be n users.

users = user1, user2, user3

How to split the users by commas using java and retrieve single value in each line and store it as either list or array without using spring framework/module.

Comment: Try to use annotation @Value and Spring Expression Language to retrieve your properties according to your needs

ex: @Value("#{'${users}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> userList;

Comment: I do not want to use Spring module

Comment: Then try to use Autowired annotation or through constructor injection to retrieve from Environment, such that:
@Autowired
private Environment environment;